# Php - A simple redirect maintaining the URL?

Tags: php, .htaccess, apache

How can I make a redirect while forcing the url to not change?

I.E.: I access http://sub.domain.com , it will open index.php where it will redirect to somewhere else while maintaining the url: http://sub.domain.com

Thanks.

Comment: You cannot 'send' the user elsewhere, the best you can hope for is playing proxy for the user.

Comment: since most uses of this are not legitimate, i would want to know why, before making any suggestions.

Comment: **EXPLANATION**
When I access my subdomain (redirected to local server) it shows an IP address instead of the subdomain alias. Example in a nutshell: I enter: http://crm.mywebsite.com and when I do it shows http://114.44.83.11/index.php  So, I'm desperately looking for a fix.

Comment: Please [EDIT](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/5544350/edit) your question.  Answers are for *answers*; StackOverflow isn't a forum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could hide the redirection via iFrames. Or possible a file_get_contents() could be used to get a new page. Not sure why you'd want to do this tho.

Comment: I thought of it, however, iframe makes my php application function incorrectly. I need a solution as a described or similar :(.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [RewriteRule](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule).  This functionality is the main point of the mod_rewrite module.

EDIT: I hesitate to post an example without testing, but it should be something like:

```
RewriteRule ^/$ /index.php
```

`^/$` just means a single / character at both the beginning and end of string (i.e. that's the only character).  This corresponds with the last / in http://sub.domain.com/.

EDIT 2: This doesn't apply, since John has clarified "somewhere else" is not the same host.

Comment: +0.5 because this is correct but doesn't use PHP as requested. Okay, I'll round it up just for you. And of course many images, scripts and stylesheets will break :)

Comment: Could you please give me an example?

Comment: @Radek, why would it have to break images, scripts, and stylesheets?  As long as you only rewrite the main page, it should be fine.

Comment: if the images, scripts and stylesheets use relative paths, like `/main.css` — oh wait, you are right :)